# ScyllaDB: Can I have multi DC cluster with different Scylla versions?

Tags: scylla

Currently I have a single DC cluster with 3 nodes running 4.1.7 version of Scylla. This setup has been running for a long time and I don't want to make changes to this DC, if possible. Now I have a requirement to add another DC cluster with 3 nodes. Can I set up this new DC with the latest stable version of Scylla? Will the two DCs be able to communicate with each other without any issues? Or am I forced to upgrade the existing DC to the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scylla supports **rolling upgrades**, which means you can indeed upgrade just some of the nodes in the cluster while the rest are still running the older version. The cluster should be able to fully work in this state - including the communication between old and new nodes. Not all upgrade paths are equally supported or have been equally tested, obviously, but most "interesting" upgrade paths (a newer release in the same major version, the next major version) are indeed supported.

That being said, while staying at a half-upgraded state for a long time is possible, it is not recommended. It also means that whatever new features or improved algorithms were introduced in the new version, the new nodes will need to avoid them until the full cluster is upgraded.

Comment: Thanks Nadav! Can I upgrade from 4.1.7 to 5 in one shot or should I upgrade from 4.1 to 4.2 and then to 4.3 and so on till I reach 5?

Answer (score 1):

OSS 4.1.7 is a pretty old OSS release from Oct 2020. The assumption that you can  add another DC running OSS 5.0 (latest OSS release from 10 days ago) to the existing cluster, is a bit of a risky one.

The supported upgrade path (QA tested) is from OSS 4.6 to 5.0. You can read more about the upgrade path here: https://docs.scylladb.com/upgrade/upgrade-opensource/

The tested upgrade route is via minor versions 4.1 --> 4.2 --> 4.3 --> 4.4 --> 4.5 --> 4.6 --> 5.0, jumping multiple minor version should work, but we can't say that it was tested.